# How can I install NPM dependencies?

Tags: javascript, github, npm, installation, dependencies

I've got a task that involves writing a code and I carried it out quite easily. I need to submit my solution to GitHub – according to the plan, I forked a certain repository and even cloned it to my hard drive using VS code. However, I was also told to install NPM dependencies to that newly created folder.

There are many manuals on Internet, but almost no one of them explains how to do it in a comprehensible way. As a beginner, I often struggle with all these new keywords, commands, etc and I would like to make things somewhat clearer. Do you have an idea how to get through it?

Comment: It's not a lot more than `npm update`, do you have a package.json file?

Comment: although I heard about Json files, I'm not even sure how they work... and how I can get them

Comment: If you cloned an existing project, you're almost certainly all ready to go. You can try `npm outdated` to see what packages need updating in your source repository (directory).

Comment: it sounds really well, but with what editor should I launch these commands? And do I need additional files anyway?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed npm, in project directory use command

```
npm install
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know how to install it or which additional programs I should use. Wish I'd simplify all that rocket science.

Comment: What operating system do u have on PC?

Comment: Download nodeJS from https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: After installation you will have npm installed, and open console/terminal. Use cd command to change directory. After you reach your project directory where is package.json use npm install command

Comment: I have Windows 10 :)

Comment: I've already got NodeJS. I need to use a standard command prompt for that, right?

Comment: yes use CMD (command promt) if tou have this project folder on desktop use command cd Desktop/folder-name example: cd Desktop/AwesomeWebsite

Comment: Wow, thank you! Seems like it worked fine. One more thing – they said that I can run "npm audit fix" to address vulnerabilities. Do I really need it, or I can just close the window and go on?

Comment: from my expiration i would say to better leave it. In some project when i did npm audit fix  it crashed my project. I'm glad you get this working, please remember to check correct answer :D

Comment: I'm so glad for your help. Most likely it's clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can start with `npm init` in your folder. Then package.json file will be created. you can add dependencies you want to add, and run `npm install`.

Comment: Thanks so much, but I don't even know how where I can execute these commands. I wanted to ask if I need to include a path to the files (e.g. C:\\PaulSmith\Desktop\MyProject and so on)

Comment: you can type "cmd" in folder top bar. and run the above command

Comment: It's clear, but I do I need to include the project's address in it?